# How do set to open an specific link on submit button based on the 2 separate radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the Code I written

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" value="fr" onclick="alert('You Have Selected Fresher Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');"> Fresher<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" value="ex" onclick="alert('You Have Selected Experienced Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');"> Experienced<br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Next" />
</form>
```

If suppose user select option 1 (say: freshers) then Link 1 (Fresher form link) Should be open.
or If select option 2 i.e experienced then experienced link should open.

[image]

Please Provide Answer with explanation, I am new to HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need script to update the `location.href' . Trigger a function on selecting radio button and update the`onclick`property using`setAttribute` method

```js
function updateLink(value) {
  if (value === "fr") {
    document.getElementById("next").setAttribute('onclick', "location.href='www.google.com'")

  } else {
    document.getElementById("next").setAttribute('onclick', "location.href='www:wikipedia.com'")

  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="cand" value="fr" onclick="updateLink(this.value)"> Fresher<br><br>
  <input type="radio" name="cand" value="ex" onclick="updateLink(this.value)"> Experienced<br><br>
  <input id="next" type="button" onclick="location.href='www.google.com';" value="Next" />
</form>
```

This demo is just based on your code. Using `addEventListener` is a better option than using inline event handler.

Comment: Hey, I want to open the specific link by clicking on submit button, I tried your code it is not working as what I expected, Please do some modifications and provide me the code

Comment: There is no `submit` button in your code. Secondly in demo it may not open as it will lead to load unsafe code or browser will block. You may try opening it running from a html file

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I add an attribute to each `radio`. When the user clicks on the button we fetch that attribute (`data-href`) and use `window.location.href` to transfer the user there. You can use `value` instead, if you find that better. Note that I removed the inline click-function and use an event for it instad.

```js
$('#clickButton').click(function(){
  var url = $('input[name=cand]:checked').data('href');
  //Goto url
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" value="fr" data-href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('You Have Selected Fresher Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');" > Fresher<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" value="ex" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/45627889/4949005" onclick="alert('You Have Selected Experienced Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');" > Experienced<br><br>
    <input type="button" id="clickButton" value="Next" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

1. Try to submit the form and prevent the default behaviour of the form using `e.preventDefault()`
2. Then change the input button type with `submit`
3. And add the `data-link` attr for Each input .For applying with window targeted link after submit

> **How its work**
>
> if you submit the form .its find the checked radio button data-link then
>   apply with `window.location`.Finaly its redirect the respected url

```js
$('from').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
window.location.href = $('input:checked').attr('data-link');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" value="fr" data-link="Fresher"onclick="alert('You Have Selected Fresher Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');" > Fresher<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="cand" data-link="Experienced" value="ex" onclick="alert('You Have Selected Experienced Level \nPlease Click Next To Proceed');" > Experienced<br><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```